# Salesforce deployment using Ant and SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, ant, continuous-integration, cicd

Our project is in this format

[image: Our project is in this format]
after using sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r src it converted to this which doesnt have package.xml

[image: after using sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r src it converted to this which doesnt have package.xml]
Using sfdx force:source:convert converted project to this format with package.xml 
[image: Using sfdx force:source:convert converted project to this format with package.xml]

Still not sure how this package.xml should be avoided to achieve partial deployment

I need a way to deploy salesforce changes using SFDX without `package.xml` for continuous integration and delivery, we use custom build system instead of Jenkins and not able to find an example of `build.xml` with **ANT** to deploy changes using SFDX while building, please help.
How to perform SFDX commands like below while building using `build.xml` is it possible?

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdAPIZip -u jzaa1 -k src/package.xml

sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -c -f ../mdAPIZip/unpackaged.zip -u jzaa1 -w 10
```

Comment: Your original question was about deploying using SFDX. Now your root question seems to be about performing partial deployments, and it's not clear what you really need. Please tell us more about your _overall objective_ to help understand your proposed solution.

Comment: Main objective is to achieve partial deployments and CICD, while reading about this i found SFDX and thought SFDX would automatically determine changes and deploy without need of Package.xml hence was the question, apologies for the confusion, any suggestions on how to do partial deployments with CI CD? @DavidReed

Answer (score 5):

The Ant-based Force.com Migration Tool and SFDX CLI are both clients of the Metadata API. You need one or the other, but generally not both, as both tools provide Metadata API deployment services. Specifically, you don't need the Force.com Migration Tool to drive Salesforce DX. You can issue commands like `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy` directly via a shell script or your build system's configuration interface.

As to `package.xml`: if you're using Metadata API-format source code (typically in a `src` folder) and not SFDX-format source code (typically in a `force-app` folder), you'll need a `package.xml` manifest.

If you're using SFDX-format code, you may not need a manifest. SFDX's `force:source` commands (such as `push`, for scratch orgs, and `deploy`, for non-scratch orgs) don't require a manifest. Likewise, converting your SFDX-format source to MDAPI-format source via `force:source:convert` will create a manifest for you to make the result deployable using the Metadata API, via the `force:mdapi:deploy` command. (Note that if you're practicing the [Org Development Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model), without using source-tracking scratch orgs, you'll likely also have a `package.xml` under the `manifest` directory).

If you aren't familiar with the two source formats and aren't currently using Salesforce DX, your code is certainly in Metadata API format and does require a manifest for deployment.

Salesforce provides [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci.htm) covering CI setup on various providers, including [sample repos](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_org_dev_repos.htm). I wrote a [series](https://www.ktema.org/2018/02/02/salesforce-dx-circleci/) of blog posts on setting up SFDX-based CI using CircleCI some time ago.

#### Partial Deployments

Partial deployments are a completely separate issue from the above.

Salesforce's tooling does not include any support for partial or delta (i.e., change-only) deployments *other than with source-tracking orgs* (such as scratch orgs), where you can use `sfdx force:source:push`.

If you're deploying to sandboxes or production, you'll have to write your own scripts to generate a `package.xml` representing some arbitrary set of changes that you wish to deploy separately. There's not a single standard way to do that; it will depend on the whole scope of your tool chain and development process.

You do not have to use partial deployments to implement CI and CD. Unless your application is truly enormous, you can deploy the entire application to your persistent environments.

Comment: Thanks a ton for reply, we are not not using salesforceDX yet , we are planning to use it by converting existing one to DX, do you have any examples of shell scripts and build.xml to perform sfdx commands? Ant had simple targets like below is there any example for SFDX where i can start. <target name="deployCodeDev"> 
  <sf:deploy username="${sfTarget.username}" password="${sfTarget.password}" serverurl="${sfTarget.serverurl}" deployroot="src" rollbackOnError="false" allowMissingFiles="true" singlePackage="true"/>
 </target>

Comment: I've added some relevant links, @nothingisimpossible,

Comment: @aoristdual I have converted entire project to SFDX why am i still getting below error?      
 Error  force-app/package.xml  package.xml  No package.xml found

Comment: @nothingisimpossible Are you trying to deploy Salesforce DX format source code using a Metadata API client?

Comment: Yes, im still confused why there is a dependency on package.xml @aoristdual

Comment: You are mixing SFDX-format source with Metadata API tools. If you deploy with a Metadata API tool, such as Ant, **you must have a `package.xml`**. There are no exceptions. If you want to deploy SFDX-format source, you must convert your source to SFDX format and deploy with SFDX.

Comment: No, I have converted using sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./temp command and trying to deploy using sfdx force:mdapi:deploy:report -u AgileDev @aoristdual

Comment: `mdapi:convert` converts *from* Metadata API source. You want `source:convert`, going the other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @david-reed I have added pictures of how we have project structure after using the convert commands in the question, please tell me which one to use for doing partial deployments without depending on package.xml, im seeing package.xml when i use source:convert , i'm not getting any good source for the right project structure